# Missing blocks for no reason?

Tags: baking

I just missed a block. I have tons of peer connections.

No endorsements in mempool?

```
Mar 16 11:35:50 - client.baking: New baking slot found (level 354707, priority 0) at 2019-03-16T11:36:41Z for tzbo after BLwRdWJqQdPg.

Mar 16 11:36:41 - client.baking: No endorsements present in the mempool. Waiting until 2019-03-16T11:37:18Z (37s) for new operations.

Mar 16 11:37:30 - client.baking: Injected block BKtSCRm4Lvif for tzbo after BLwRdWJqQdPg (level 354707, priority 0, fitness 00::0000000000a7b480, operations 22+0+0+0).
```

Tzscan.io doesn't show block 354707 as 'Last Baking' and under Cycle Details - 354707 is listed twice?

[image]

[image]

Comment: How much RAM, SSD and CPU speed?

Comment: Running 16GB RAM, 1TB HD, 2.3 GHz i7

Answer (score 2):

Your block didn't include enough endorsements - your block had a fitness of `0000000000a7b480` which is `10990720` - the block that was actually included [at that level](https://tzscan.io/354707) had a higher fitness of `10990726`. Unfortunately having "tons of peer connections" wasn't enough to receive as many endorsements as the other block, or endorsements came in late giving the later blocks an advantage.