# Why did my baker lose a block?

Tags: baking, block

My baker address is `tz1XXayQohB8XRXN7kMoHbf2NFwNiH3oMRQQ` and I lost the block `BMP5PSZ97etLozjnSERt2LLHbPPwNXbAhmNf7WNCWnqkwZHWYXo`, and I would like to understand why?

When I check the baker log, I get:

```
Mar 24 05:07:08 - client.baking: New baking slot found (level 365858, priority 0) at 2019-03-24T10:07:51Z for tezoscat after BL4VioWqcd3A.
Mar 24 05:07:51 - client.baking: No endorsements present in the mempool. Waiting until 2019-03-24T10:08:28Z (37s) for new operations.
Mar 24 05:08:39 - client.baking: Injected block BLExUox6QDgR for tezoscat after BL4VioWqcd3A (level 365858, priority 0, fitness 00::0000000000ad4481, operations 20+0+0+2).
```

Comment: I think this question is going to be duplicated often... Here are two more at least: https://tezos.stackexchange.com/q/279 https://tezos.stackexchange.com/q/784

Answer (score 4):

The priority 1 baker (Foundation Baker 5) stole this baking right from you due to its higher fitness (i.e. their block received 2 more endorsements than yours, 33 to 31), as you can see [here](https://tzscan.io/heads?level=365858).

Difficult to say why this happened, as it can have multiple reasons, such as connectivity issues to other nodes, your node's hardware (especially performance of your hard drive), internet speed, etc.

You can see on TzScan that your block is stored in the chain later than the priority 1 block pointing to connectivity issues.

Comment: Thanks, I switch a new vps vender, everything is good now.